# PIG Cassandra ERROR 2118 Could not get input splits

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I started off trying to do simple pig+cassandra integration with this tutorial from datastax: http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaPigExRel.html

but when i try to store the result into cql, i get this error:

> Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR
>   2118: Could not get input splits
>           at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:279)

any ideas whats happening? i read some answers here, referring to changing my PIG_PARTITIONER to Murmur3Partitioner

which i already did and it still happens. is it configuration issue?

```
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that after doing:

```
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
```

i need to do source ~/.bashrc and do pig from that particular console.

though I get another error, but I think this case is solved.